# tfs how do l create an iteration and link a work item to it in C#

Tags: c#, tfs

tfs how do l create an iteration and link a work item to it in C#. In the Api is there a way of creating a new iteration programmatically in C# and link a task to it, so that l can be able to view it on the visual studio site and see the task under the iteration
thank you

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Comment: What TFS version do you use?

Comment: Hi Thank you for the replies, I am using Tfs 2015 thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use REST API to create an iteration and create a task under this iteration.

[Create an iteration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/classification-nodes#get-an-iteration):

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/iterations?api-version=1.0

        Content-Type: application/json

        {
          "name": "Final Iteration",
          "attributes": {
            "startDate": "2016-10-27T00:00:00Z",
            "finishDate": "2016-10-31T00:00:00Z"
          }

    }
```

[Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item):

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}//_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=1.0

Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "XXXX"
  },

 {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "value": "XXXX\\Final Iteration"
  }
]
```

Then you can check the project on the codeplex: https://vsorest.codeplex.com/,  which shows how to use VSO REST APIs using C#.